# $.ajax function not working when <form> is used

Tags: jsp, jquery, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I am learning ajax. Please find below code,

```
     <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org         /TR/html4/loose.dtd">
     <html>
     <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
     <title>Insert title here</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/MyApp/js/jquery.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         function doAjax() {
             alert('yes');
           $.ajax({
             url: 'register.html',
             data: ({name : "me"}),
             success: function(data) {
               $('#time').html(data);
             }
           });
         }
       </script>  
     </head>
     <body>
     <form action="">
     <button id="demo" onclick="doAjax()" title="Button">Get the time!</button>
     <div id="time">
     </div>
     </form>
     </body>
     </html>
```

This code makes successful ajax call to my spring controller and return data only if i remove form tags otherwise it wont show ajax message (and no error as well).

I checked logs. If i remove form tag, last request received is to 'register.html' which is very correct. If i put form tag, on click of button, request goes to 'hello.html' which is the page which holds above code. I am not able to understand how is this happening.

One thing I was suspecting is form is getting sumitted. but how can this happen if i am not firing sumit event on click of button.

I need to have form tag on this page so please advice.

controller functions below,

```
     @RequestMapping("/hello")
           public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
           return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", "Spring MVC Demo");
           }

     @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
           public @ResponseBody String registerUser(@RequestParam String name) {
             String result = "Time for registration" + name + " is " + new Date().toString();
             return result;
           }
```

Comment: What tag are you talking about?

Comment: it works only if i remove form tags.. it was not shown earlier

Comment: Please post your controller as well

Comment: try moving the button outside the form tags. You could even put the whole form in the ajax file.

Comment: @ Codeguy007 - I am new to Ajax so can you be more specific please when you say "You could even put the whole form in the ajax file"?

Comment: in register.html. if the point of the button is to bring up the registration form then it stands to reason that the whole form would be in register.html.

Comment: I have updated my answer take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, If you use the button tag inside the html form browser may interpret as the submit request. Which is why you do a button press with the form its no more an ajax request. Which could be noted when you render the homepage the url would be something like localhost:8000/home but after the button click url would be localhost:8000/home? which denotes there was a normal get request

If you still want the button to create a ajax request inside the form do something like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
    $('button').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        doAjax();
    })
 })


     function doAjax() {
         alert('yes');
       $.ajax({
         url: '/register/',
         data: ({name : "me"}),
         success: function(data) {
           $('#time').html(data);
         }
       });
     }
   </script>  
 </head>
 <body>
    <form action="">
 <button id="demo" title="Button">Get the time!</button>
 </form>
 <div id="time">
 </div>
```

Secondly, try changing the url in your Ajax function to "/register.html/". Mind the slashes. Since it could be possible in some cases where jquery would suggest append the given url to the page's url.

For example, if your page url is localhost:8000/home. The request generated could be localhost:8000/home/register. So, its always a good idea to use slashes when you define your urls.

Laslty, try using some other extension instead of html since, html is conventionally used to generate static content and convent for dynamic content is htm. Its just a convention for a good practice rest is your choice.

Comment: surprised to see that button tag inside the html form browser may interpret as the submit request. Thanks Raunak. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the button to submit the form, give it a type of "submit". Also, instead of using an inline onclick handler for the button element, define a submit handler for the form.

Comment: i just edited the post. I dont want to submit a form. What i wanted to mention is, above example works only if i remove "form" tags.

Comment: Not sure I understand why you're using form tags then.

Comment: I have not completed the entire coding of this page. I need to have form because i will be submitting form with some action going forward.